# Why does scipy bessel root finding not return roots at zero?

Tags: python, scipy, bessel-functions

I am trying to use code which uses Bessel function zeros for other calculations. I noticed the following piece of code produces results that I consider unexpected.

```
    import scipy
    from scipy import special

    scipy.special.jn_zeros(1,2)
```

I would expect the result from this call to be

```
    array([0., 3.83170597])
```

instead of

```
    array([3.83170597, 7.01558667])
```

Is there a reason a reason why the root at x=0.0 is not being returned?

From what I can see the roots are symmetric along the x-axis except for any found at the origin, but I do not think this would be enough of a reason to leave off the root completely.

The computer I am using has python version 2.7.10 installed and is using scipy version 0.19.0

P.S. the following function is what I am trying to find the zeros of

```
    scipy.special.j1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be convention to not count the zero at zero, see for example [ħere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionZeros.html). Maybe it is considered redundant?

Comment: This is my speculation, but maybe only for j0 is there not a root at 0. So I could see the redundancy there.In that case leaving it up to the user to handle the one special case is fine. Thank you!